# Why use $-\dim(|A|)$ as target entropy in soft actor critic

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement [Soft Actor-Critic with automatic Entropy tuning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05905).

One thing I noticed is that the authors, and also the majority of implementations of SAC use $-\text{dim}(|\mathcal{A}|)$ as entropy target $\bar{\mathcal{H}}$ in the loss function of $\alpha$, and I am confused where this exact value came from. I have read the answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561624/choosing-target-entropy-for-soft-actor-critic-sac-algorithm), but I am still not fully convinced.

I do understand the intuition behind setting $\bar{\mathcal{H}}$ proportional to $\text{dim}(|\mathcal{A}|)$. Let's say, for example, we consider the target distribution of $\text{tanh}(\bf{u})$ to be $\text{Uniform}(-1, 1)$ for each dimension (I am not sure if this is a good assumption though), then the entropy target should be $\text{dim}(|\mathcal{A}|) \ln(2)$. But I am not sure why the majority of the implement uses exactly $-\text{dim}(|\mathcal{A}|)$.

Is there any specific reason for this setting? Or, are there any papers or articles about how the target entropy setting affects the performance of SAC?

Edit:

Just in case, the loss function of $\alpha$ I am referring to is Eq18:

$$
J(\alpha) = \mathbb{E}_{\bf{a}_t \sim \pi_t} [- \alpha \log \pi_t(\bf{a}_t | \bf{s}_t) - \alpha \bar{\mathcal{H}}]
$$

Answer (score 3):

If you are minimizing a loss function $f$, and there is a function $g$ that is proportional to $f$ something like this
$$ g = k \cdot f $$
then by minimizing $f$ you are also minimizing $g$.

It also extends to all transformations of f that do not change the ordering.  If for a transformation $h(f)$ if you were to sort both $f$ and $h(f)$ and the order of the result is identical, then minimizing on $f$ is the same as minimizing on $h(f)$.  Its said a little awkwardly, sorry.

**Positive examples**:

lets say that $f=\operatorname{abs}(x)$, you could minimize $h(f)=f^2$ and get the    minimum would be the same.

lets say that $f=\operatorname{abs}(x)$ and $x$ is constrained to $0<x$.  you could minimize $h(f)=\log(f)$ and get to the same location.

**Negative examples** (how to do it wrong):

lets say that $f=\operatorname{abs}(x)$ and $x$ is NOT constrained to $0<x$.  you could minimize $h(f)=\log(f)$ and you would run into the discontinuity at $x=0$ and your optimization would fail.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is exactly connected to the selection of entropy target $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$? The explanation is to vague and I really do not see the connection with the loss function in this answer and the loss function used for adjusting $\alpha$.

Comment: Where it says "then the entropy target should be $dim(|A|)ln(2)$" you are differing about a constant of proportionality.  I will check the paper, but some folks maximize the negative loss and others minimize the negative gain.  Signs can get lost, but inverting during minimize can be a very bad thing.  It might be a typo.  Let me check.

Comment: The $\text{dim}(|\mathcal{A}|) \ln (2)$ part was just an example that is not even sure if it is valid or not. Also, I wouldn't say the loss function for $\alpha$ used in the paper is proportional to $\bar{\mathcal{H}}$.